# Split colon delimited string into parts

Tags: java, string, split

I am new to Java and I was experimenting with regex. I want to split a string into several capturing groups and store them in a String array.

```
String[] pieces="User: text..text text".split("^(\\w):(.*)$");
System.out.println(pieces[0]);
//pices[0]="User: text..text text"
```

I want to split `"User: text..text text"` using regex: `"^(\\w:)(.*)$"` into the number of the capturing groups(which for this case is 2) provided in the regex. What I expect is:

```
pieces[0]="User"
pieces[1]="text...text text"
```

There might be a string like `"User: foo:bar mr:potato"`. I don't want to split at every `:` character, I just want `"User:"` and `" foo:bar mr: potato"`. I want to split this without using any loops, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java also has a `split()` method that limits the number of times the pattern is applied

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)

```
String[] pieces="User: text..text text".split(":",2);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need can be achieved using the split() function provided by String class in Java. 
`String[] pieces = "User: text..text text".split(":");`

Comment: Yes, but there might be strings that contain `:` more than once, so that would not get me what I want. `"User: foo:bar"` this will split into 3 parts, I want to split just `"User"` and `" foo:bar"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split by `:`

```
public class WordSpliter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] pieces="User: text..text text".split(": ",2);
        for (String piece : pieces) {
            System.out.println(piece);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what about `"User: hello: mr: potato:chips"`? I want to split just at the very first `:` character, not at every single `:`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
String text = "User: text..text text";
String[] pieces = text.split(": ",2);
System.out.println(pieces[0]);
System.out.println(pieces[1]);
```

With regex you could do it this way.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+): (.*)$");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Both print

```
User
text..text text
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but there might be a string like `"User: foo:bar mr:potato"`. This will split at every `:` character, I just want `"User:"` and `" foo:bar mr: potato"`

Comment: We can only answer the question based on how it is presented.  You need to be  specific on the contents of the string.

Comment: My answer did what you asked.  It won't split at every : because of the $.  I also limited the String split to an array size of 2.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, I really liked your answer, I wanted the split parts to be stored in a String array, I just didn't notice that you edited and added `String[] pieces = text.split(": ",2)`. This does exactly what I wanted :D. Thanks!

Comment: @Terrarium  Not a problem.  Just wanted to know what was going on.  Really glad you got the answer you needed since that's the important thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use actual Regex pattern/matchers its set up like this

```
    String inputString = "User: text..text text";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\w):(.*)$");  
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++){
            //Go through all groups in this match
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
```